# disable / encrypt cookies in react-native (android webview)

Tags: react-native, security, cookies, axios, android-webview

We use axios with react-native in our project to make http requests. Security team found out that all cookies received from server are located in /data/data/appfolder/app_webview/Cookies in plain text.

As I understand react-native android class com.facebook.react.modules.network.ForwardingCookieHandler using native webview cookiemanager saves all cookies to this file and they are unencrypted.

My questions are

1) Is it possible to not save / disable particular cookies (or all cookies)?

2) Is it insecure to store session cookies like that or should I encrypt cookies someway if some of them cannot be disabled (required for correct app work)?

I've tried to set cache-control: no-cache="set-cookie". Call CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookies(false)
None of these are working

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm struggling with the same.